# Isotropic and anisotropic elements

Tags: number-theory

Let $q$ be a quadratic form on a vector space $V$ over a field $F$.

A non-zero vector $v \in V$ is said to be *isotropic* if $q(v) = 0$. Otherwise $v$ is said to be *anisotropic*.

If $a,b \in V$ are anisotropic vectors, is it true then, that the sum $a+b$ and the difference $a-b$ are anisotropic, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false: consider the following as a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$: $$\Phi((x_1,x_2))=x_1^2-x_2^2$$

then $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are both anisotropic but $\Phi((1,0)+(0,1))=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let the quadratic form
$$q\colon\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R;\quad (x,y)\mapsto x^2-y^2$$
and then the isotropic cone is 
$$C_q=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1)\}\cup \operatorname{span}\{(-1,1)\}$$
so let $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(0,1)$ and $c=(1,0)$ so $a-b=(1,1)\in C_q$  and $a+c=(2,2)\in C_q$
.